# How to set header to return an excel file as reponse and download with specified name without creating temporary .xls file at server

Tags: java, rest, apache-poi, jax-rs

I am using below code for the same.

```
@POST
@Path("getExelStreamDocDB")
@Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
public Response getExelStreamDocDB(String req);
```

Implementation of above service containing below piece of code.

```
byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);
ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok((Object) encoded);
responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Provider.xls\"");
```

I am using Apache POI to create XLS file .
Please help.

Comment: try StreamingOutput, eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/12012867/987959

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50401477/2587435