# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/octet-stream

Tags: jax-rs

HTTP 500 Internal Server Error] with root cause
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/octet-stream, type=class za.co.XXXXXXX.XXX.Status, genericType=class za.co.XXXXXXX.XXX.Status.

I tried adding below dependencies but it never worked for me.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
   <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: MOXy is for JSON but you are trying to send application/octet-stream? Why are you trying to send octet-stream?

Comment: As a response and generating Zipped files out of CSV. that's the reason used octet-stream. as a suggestions it was suggested to use above jar but it never worked for you. Could your please specify what I should look for.

Comment: You need to understand how Java objects get serialized into the response stream. This happens with the use of MessageBodyWriters. And there is no writer that handles octet-stream and arbitrary Java types. The universal writers can handle octet-stream and StreamingOutput, InputStream, byte[], and File. So if you use one of these types, it will work out the box. Otherwise you will need to implement your own MessageBodyWriter that can handle octet-stream and whatever Java type you were trying to use.

Comment: Have a look at this similar post https://stackoverflow.com/q/50400719/2587435

Comment: Is there any chance anything related to Tomcat 7,8  server configuration as same Code is working in production but not in lower environment.

Comment: Like I said, the only way it would work is if either you are using one of the (four) Java types I mentioned, or you have a custom MessageBodyWriter that handles your desired type and application/octet-stream.